# Bone in wrong position when apply animation

Tags: animation, rigging, bones

I'm trying to use some Mixamo's animations on a character (rigged with Mixamo too) and when I go to "Dope Sheet > Action editor" and change the character animation to the new one, the bones are very wrong. I've seen lots of videos but still, I'm missing something

The image below shows the 2 armatures (the character's one and the imported one). How can I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I figured out that this was happening because of the different rest poses of the armatures. Because my character had legs and arms in different positions, the animation was weird. Fixed the rest pose and all works fine. Hope it helps someone.